# How to hide slash command to specific user or channel Discord.js v13

Tags: permissions, discord.js, command, hide, slash

Is it possible to hide slash command in discord.js v13.1.0 ?
I tried to add some permission but nothing that i found worked like the

*" command.permissions.add({ "permission array" }) "*

If there is a way to do it it would be amazing

I saw that the support saw that issue but do you have any idea about when they would add this feature ?

Answer (score 3):

I just used the discord interface. Here's what I did:

- **(1)** Right click your server
- **(2)** Go to Server Settings -> Integrations
- **(3)** Scroll down to Bots and Apps and click Manage next to your bot
- **(4)** Click Add Roles or Members, or click Channels depending on if you want to restrict to specific roles, users, or channels
- **(5)** Once you add them, click the X to restrict their access to the command. Now they won't be able to see it anymore.

**Important Note:** Make sure to view the server as a non-admin role or switch accounts to a non-admin user to test the new permissions. Otherwise, it won't work. To view as another role, go to Server Settings -> Roles, then select a non-admin role, scroll to the bottom and select View Server As Role.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[discordjs guide](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-command-permissions.html#user-permissions)**, you need to use `ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager#set()` or `ApplicationCommandPermissionsManager#add()`:

#### using set()

```js
const fullPermissions = [
    {
        id: '123456789012345678',
        permissions: [{
            id: '224617799434108928',
            type: 'USER',
            permission: false,
        }],
    },
    {
        id: '876543210987654321',
        permissions: [{
            id: '464464090157416448',
            type: 'ROLE',
            permission: true,
        }],
    },
];

await client.guilds.cache.get('123456789012345678')?.commands.permissions.set({ fullPermissions });
```

#### using add()

```js
if (!client.application?.owner) await client.application?.fetch();

const command = await client.guilds.cache.get('123456789012345678')?.commands.fetch('876543210987654321');

const permissions = [
    {
        id: '224617799434108928',
        type: 'USER',
        permission: false,
    },
];

await command.permissions.add({ permissions });
```

Comment: I already saw that but the add method don't work

Comment: And even with this what is the first id that is used in the set

Comment: You cannot "hide" slash command for your bot like that as far as I know. The permission system disables slash command for the specified user/role, making it unusable for them. You can disable slash commands from channel or role settings, which would hide all slash commands from the channel except system commands.

Comment: But still This way with permission is not working for me, I dont realy understand where or how i can use it

Comment: maybe it's because you have "administrator" or something? have you checked that??

Comment: administrator instead of permission ?*

Comment: Slash command permissions don't work like traditional permissions. See https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/2315 for more info